# How can I make a Property Read-only Declared in Interface in C#

Tags: c#, properties

I'm using Interfaces for Dependency Injection.

Here is my Interface

```
public interface IRepository 
{
    bool IsTxOpened { get; set; }
    //.....
}
```

And Implementation Class

```
public class RepositoryImpl : IRepository, IDisposable
{
    //.........
    public bool IsTxOpened { get { return _txIsOpened; } private set { _txIsOpened = value; }}
    //................
}
```

And Here is my Controller Class

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //.........
    private IRepository _repository;

    public EmployeeController(IRepository repository)
    {           
        _repository = repository;
    }
    //...........
}
```

I can not mark **set** as private in Interface. I need **Set** and **Get** both and I do not want to expose **Set** to (I do not want to make it public) other classes. Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Just remove "set;" from the interface.

Comment: @Peter Duniho can I have Set in My Implementation class?, Because I want to change backing field value within the class only

Comment: What happened when you tried it? (Hint: you should have just tried it, and if you had, you'd know the answer to that question already :) ).

Comment: Implementing an interface just says "I can do everything that is defined in the interface." It does *not* say "I cannot do anything else."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:-

```
public interface IRepository 
{
    bool IsTxOpened { get; }
    //.....
}
```

Omitting the **set** accessor, makes the property read-only.